# how to store the data in a object array, which collected from data base?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, pojo

**Here, i have coded to get data from DB. I want to store the data in Object Array(POJO).
How to do it?**    This code can also insert Data into DB, but omit it.

```
import java.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class Jdbc {
static int id[] = new int[10];
static String name[] = new String[10];
static int salary[] = new int[10];
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    try {
          Statement stmt;
          ResultSet rs;
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dwr";
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "1234");
          System.out.println("URL: " + url);
          System.out.println("Connection: " + con);
          stmt = con.createStatement();
          System.out.println("Enter EmpId:");
          BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          int empId=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
          System.out.println("Enter Name:");
          BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          String name1=br1.readLine();
          System.out.println("Enter Salary:");
          BufferedReader br2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          int salary1=Integer.parseInt(br2.readLine());
          stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO employee set EmpId='"+empId+"', Name='"+name1+"', salary='"+salary1+"';");
          stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
          rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * " + "from employee ORDER BY EmpId");
          System.out.println("Display all results:");
          int i = 0;
          while(rs.next()){
            id[i]= rs.getInt("Empid");
            name[i]= rs.getString("Name");
            salary[i]= rs.getInt("Salary");
            System.out.println("\n EmpId " + id[i]+ "\n name " + name[i] + "\n salary " + salary[i]);
          }

    }catch( Exception e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
}
    Jdbc pojo = new Jdbc();

}
}
```

Comment: Think of a database table as *the array*

Comment: What, how to do it. I am newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `get` methods provided to populate the fields of the object one at a time, so if you have an object named employee, that takes in 3 arguments (id, name and salary), you can have something like this:

```
List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
while(rs.next())
{
employee.add(new Employee(rs.getInt("Empid"), rs.getString("Name"),rs.getInt("Salary"));
}
```

Or else, you can use an ORM Tools, like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) and use it to retrieve objects as shown [here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/247.html)

P.S. The Java code I have provided is more like Pseudo code. I have not tested it.